# WinAPI: get typed character

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, keylogger

I am currently developing a programm called "Key-O-Meter". This programm should track every input made with the keyboard on Windows. The tracked keys will be used to create a statistic at some other time. Unfortunately I am facing problems in determining which character was typed. The code below only prints the character on the keyboard (i.e. "a" if a was pressed, but not "A" if shift + "a" were pressed). Special characters don't work at all.

Is there a better WinAPI function than `MapVirtualKeyA` that provides this functionality?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

LRESULT WINAPI lowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam);

/**
 *
 */
int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
        LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
    //add hook
    HHOOK hook;
    hook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL,
            (HOOKPROC) lowLevelKeyboardProc, NULL, 0);

    //start message loop
    MSG message;
    while (GetMessage(&message, NULL, 0, 0) != 0) {
        TranslateMessage(&message);
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }

    //disable hook
    UnhookWindowsHookEx(hook);
    return 0;
}

/**
 *
 */
LRESULT WINAPI lowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam) {
    if (wParam == WM_KEYDOWN) {
        //handle normal keydown
        PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (PKBDLLHOOKSTRUCT) lParam;

        char keyChar = MapVirtualKeyA(hookStruct->vkCode, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR);
        cout << keyChar << endl;
    }

    return CallNextHookEx(0, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: You don't appear to be handling modifier keys at all

Comment: How can I handle them? Please provide a small example

Comment: You've got bigger problems. You've got a knowledge deficit. Having someone else write the code for you won't help you learn. What you are lacking is a solid grounding in how Windows handles input, virtual keys and so on. You need to learn about that before proceeding.

Answer (score 2):

MapVirtualKey() has no way of knowing if a modifier key was pressed. You might want to look into [ToAscii()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [ToUnicode()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Both of them take the keyboard state as input.

The keyboard state can be obtained using [GetKeyboardState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)  or [GetAsyncKeyState()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)